# Thread come out from waitting state without notify() in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

How can below code get executed as ThreadB not executing notify(),ThreadA should remain in waitting state.
Is it possible that a thread can come out from waitting state as the another thread completes its execution.

```
public class ThreadA extends Thread
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ThreadB B = new ThreadB();
        B.start();
        synchronized (B) {
            try {
                /* Go into waiting state */
                B.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            System.out.println(B.result);
        }
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread
{
    int result;

    public void run()
    {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                result = result + i;
            }
            // notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
55
```

Comment: What do you think `B.wait()` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: A thread gets on this waiting list by executing the wait() method of the target object. From that moment, it doesn't execute any further instructions until the notify() method of the target object is called.

Comment: So which thread will block in your example? The main thread that actually called `B.wait()` or the thread represented by the `Thread` object referenced by `B`?

Comment: i am thinking it will be main() i.e. ThreadA

Comment: So that won't block the thread represented by `B` from executing. Note that you should never synchronize, `notify` or `wait` on `Thread` instances.

Comment: Nor should you ever `wait()` unless you are waiting in a loop for some testable condition:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: i don't feel like looking this up but if you want a thread b to only start when thread a finishes - java's executor thread pool would be what you want.

Comment: then why the ThreadA executing the println statement as it is in waiting state

Comment: Because when thread `B` terminates, it `notify`s itself (the corresponding `Thread` object). Don't use these methods with `Thread`.

Comment: Thank you  Sotirios Delimanolis!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the JavaDocs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) and read the documentation for Thread you will see that it says never to use wait, notify, or notifyAll on a Thread. Internally, Thread.join() and thread death use wait and notifyAll to accomplish the join functionality

Answer (score 1):

When the thread ends/exists it will `notifyAll` on its instance. This is what youre seeing.